# Force model fields in Django

Tags: django

When creating a model in Django like this example:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I noticed some problem (not sure if that's best word) with this approach. There is nothing preventing you from creating something like:

```
musician = Musician()
musician.save()
```

effectively having `primary_key` value equal to `None`. I would like to force user to set `first_name`, but frankly speaking I cannot find any simple solution for that.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **don't** set `first_name` as primary key. Just leave the default primary key as the `id` field. A primary key needs to be unique (a `first_name` isn't) and should not be something a user enters.

Second, it's true that you cannot enforce a `CharField` to not be empty at the database level. But you can enforce it at the code level, so that anytime you create a Django `Form` and validate it, it will raise an error.

In fact, Django does it automatically for you, in your case. By default `first_name` is a `required` field, since you didn't set `blank=True`.

So if you do:

```
musician = Musician()
musician.full_clean()
```

this raises a `ValidationError`.

If you create a form for your model (which is what you need if you want users to create a `Musician`):

```
class MusicianForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Musician
        fields = '__all__'

form = MusicianForm(data={})
form.instance.first_name
# ''
form.is_valid()
# False
form.save()
# ValueError: The Musician could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

You'll also see that if you register `Musician` in `admin.py` for django admin site, you can't leave any of the fields empty. It just won't save.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that `first_name` is stupid choice, but it was only for example purpose. In fact I'll be using `OneToOne` mapped field from another model. As for the form it is good to know. But this works only for form. In case I'd like to do check model in unit test I'm unable to. Anyhow, thanks for clarification on forms.

Comment: In your unit tests, you should use the `full_clean()` method on the model to check whether or not it's valid.